# Django - ValidationError on saving a model instance containing DateField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm still on [this](http://dpaste.com/661995/) view. Now I have a `ValidationError` while trying to save the model instance. The error is:

> Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format

The `DateField` is correctly filled, the type of instance passed to model is unicode. I have to do something like a cast from unicode to datetime or there's something I'm doing wrong before...?

[This](http://dpaste.com/661996/) is the traceback.

Any idea?

Thanx

Comment: Can you show your `models.py`?

Comment: here it is: http://dpaste.com/662000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the form is valid through `form.is_valid()`, consider working with `cleaned_data` instead of working directly with the `request.POST`:

```
if form.is_valid():
    ...
    fattura.data = form.cleaned_data["data"]
    fattura.diate = Decimal(form.cleaned_data["diate"])
    ...
```